# ChromeDriver 78 Seems To Be Disabling allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal Flag

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

## The Problem

A few Chrome releases ago, [Chrome deprecated a feature allowing for synchronous XHR during page dismissal](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912). After several business complained of unforeseen impacts to business, they decided to default the behavior in Chrome 80 and allow for temporary workaround up until Chrome 82.

It seems that after upgrading to Chrome/ChromeDriver 78, we are seeing behavior in our application that is consistent with sync XHR on unload event being blocked. This behavior is only when ChromeDriver opens Chrome, I cannot reproduce when opening Chrome manually. This occurs even when no ChromeOptions are specified when opening Driver. While in ChromeDriver generated Chrome window, I navigate to `chrome:\\flags` and search for the `#allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal` flag, I see it's set to 'default'. Upon setting to 'Enabled', our issue goes away. However, when I check this flag in my manually launched Chrome window, it's also set to 'default'.
[image]

## My Question

1. Why does it seem behavior is different when launching via ChromeDriver vs. a manually opened Chrome session?
2. What is the correct way to force ChromeDriver to set the #allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal to enabled via `ChromeOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer question 2:

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--enable-features=AllowSyncXHRInPageDismissal");
```

Comment: I was able to use 'chromeOptions.AddArgument("--enable-features=AllowSyncXHRInPageDismissal");' and this resolved the issue. However, I'd still like to figure out why ChromeDriver is behaving differently than if I were to just open up Chrome.